# How do i determine the nth weekday of a given date in php

Tags: php, datetime, date

I am working on a calendar script where in i need to repeat a calendar event like
"Repeat on every 1st Tuesday of every month"

In the example above. How do you get the "1st"?

for example today is June 12,2009 this would mean it's "2nd Friday of June" How do i get the "2nd"?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Divide by 7 and round up:

```
ceil(date('j') / 7);
```

Comment: Heh I was trying to think of how to solve this problem. This didn't occur to me. Clean, elegant, +1.

Comment: haha yeah, it took me a minute and then I was like "oh, of course!"

Comment: Also, remember that date take an optional second parameter (timestamp), so this solution could be reused for an arbitrary date.

Comment: You're awesome Nick! Good job.

Comment: @nickf  Wow really. I missed it completely. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
<?php

$date = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date('y')));

echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date.'next tuesday'));

?>
```

The first line creates a date thats the first day of this month.
The second line get the next tuesday from $date.

You can do much more see [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [mktime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) and [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Comment: you're doing the reverse of what the OP is asking. Given a date, tell me how many Fridays (or whatever) there have been before this in this month, not what is the date of the nth Friday?

Answer (score 0):

```
function dayOfWeek($d, $m, $y) 
{ 
    static $t = [0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4]; 
    $y -= $m < 3; 
    return ($y + $y / 4 - $y / 100 + $y / 400 + $t[$m - 1] + $d) % 7; 
} 

// 30th August 2010
// 0: sunday - 6: saturday
echo dayOfWeek(30, 8, 2010);
```